# Mapping error : Missing map from "Group" to "GroupDto". (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mapping

I'm using EntityFramework as a DataLayer and DTO to transfer data between layer.

so when i wanna display for example a list of "Groups", i get this error message :

```
Missing map from Group to GroupDto. Create using Mapper.CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>
```

[image]

my architecture

[image]

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the exception message and creating a mapping between the two classes?

Comment: i don't know how to create mapping with two classes !

Comment: The error is pretty specific: `Mapper.CreateMap<Group,GroupDto>`

Comment: witche place i put this mapper ?

Comment: It just needs to have run once before you attempt to map. In a web app I would put it in `Application_Start`.

Comment: i can't found Application_start file !

Comment: It's not a file, it's a method in `Global.Asax`.

Comment: there is no file with this name 'Global.Asax'

Comment: There should be one in your web app somewhere, its a core part of an asp.net web app.

Comment: i searched in my directory but there is no file with "asax" extension